# How can I get node URL in Twig?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I created a page of my VIEW - views-view-fields--MYFOOBAR.html.twig

I managed to output the URL of my image field via:

```
{{ file_url(row._entity.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}
```

Also I managed how to output normal data fields like text or number:

```
{{ row._entity.field_MYTEXTFIELD.value }}
```

Sorry for stupid question, but how can I get URL to my node? I need something like:

```
<a class="full-item-title" href="NODE URL">{{ row._entity.field_MyH1Text.value }}</a>
```

Comment: You should click the checkmark besides @MaximStrutinskiy 's answer to indicate if it is the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{# Link to node page. #}

    <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}">{{ 'View node page'|t }}</a>
```

Look at the official documentation: [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates)